# how to get a line from an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object, and I'm not sure how to get one line, then get its value
Example:
Object:

```
{
    id: 101,
    name: "example"
}
```

I'd like to get the value of name which would return "example".
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Objects don't have "lines".  They have properties and you can read a property of an object with `obj.propName`.  So, if you have `let obj = {id: 101, name: "example"}`, then you can reference `obj.name` to get `"example"`.

Comment: This isn't real! JavaScript is well-documented, and Internet is full of tutorials, there should not be any troubles to find and learn the very basics. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of name, you can use this:

```js
var user = {
  id: 101,
  name: "example"
};

console.log(user.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys(obj)` will return all the keys that object got. Use `obj.name` or `obj['name']` to get the value